# PostgreSQL connect asynchronously with epoll_wait

Tags: c, linux, postgresql

I whant to work with PostgreSQL (9.1) asynchronously in my linux project. For this I have to use epoll_wait (because of other parts of the application). The goal will be to finally use epoll in edge triggered mode. But I cannot make the connection process work, even in non edge triggered mode. And I don't know why. However, when user name and password is correct, it works. But it also have to work when the password is wrong, too. In that case, I get some error I don't understand. :-/ Here is the code I use (the connection is already initialized with an PQconnectStart() and a parameter list that works fine with PQconnectdb()):

```
void ConnectDB(PGconn * connection)
{
    int pq_fd = PQsocket(connection);
    int epoll_fd = epoll_create1(0);
    struct epoll_event event;
    struct epoll_event *eventList = (epoll_event *)calloc(64, sizeof(epoll_event));

    event.data.fd = pq_fd;
    event.events = EPOLLOUT | EPOLLERR;
    epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, pq_fd, &event);

    while (true) {
        PostgresPollingStatusType pt = PQconnectPoll(connection);
        switch (pt)
        {
        case PGRES_POLLING_OK:
            printf("*** connection established!\n");
            return;

        case PGRES_POLLING_FAILED:
            printf("*** connection failed: %s\n", PQerrorMessage(connection));
            return;

        case PGRES_POLLING_ACTIVE:
            printf("   --- poll result: PGRES_POLLING_ACTIVE\n");
            break;

        case PGRES_POLLING_READING:
            printf("   --- poll result: PGRES_POLLING_READING - Modifiing epoll to EPOLLIN\n");
            event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLERR;
            if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, PQsocket(connection), &event) == -1) {
                printf("epoll_ctl() error: %u: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                exit(1);
            }
            break;

        case PGRES_POLLING_WRITING:
            printf("   --- poll result: PGRES_POLLING_WRITING - Modifiing epoll to EPOLLOUT\n");
            event.events = EPOLLOUT | EPOLLERR;
            if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, PQsocket(connection), &event) == -1) {
                printf("epoll_ctl() error: %u: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                exit(1);
            }
            break;
        }

        int n = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, eventList, 64, -1);
        if (n == -1) {
            printf("epoll_wait() error: %u: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output I get:

```
--- poll result: PGRES_POLLING_WRITING - Modifiing epoll to EPOLLOUT
--- poll result: PGRES_POLLING_READING - Modifiing epoll to EPOLLIN
--- poll result: PGRES_POLLING_READING - Modifiing epoll to EPOLLIN
--- poll result: PGRES_POLLING_READING - Modifiing epoll to EPOLLIN
--- poll result: PGRES_POLLING_WRITING - Modifiing epoll to EPOLLOUT
--- poll result: PGRES_POLLING_READING - Modifiing epoll to EPOLLIN
--- poll result: PGRES_POLLING_READING - Modifiing epoll to EPOLLIN
--- poll result: PGRES_POLLING_WRITING - Modifiing epoll to EPOLLOUT
epoll_ctl() error: 2: No such file or directory
```

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The postgresql client library first tries an ssl-connection and if that fails, it retries without ssl. This is done regardless of the reason *why* the connection failed and it does so without notifying the caller at all. So even if the error is a *wrong password*, the client library will close the filedescriptor and reopen the socket connection for plaintext.

If a filedescriptor is closed, it is automatically *removed* from the epoll-set (which results in your "No such file or directory" error message). So you would have to manually re-add it:

```
if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, PQsocket(connection), &event) == -1) {
    if (errno == ENOENT) {
        epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, PQsocket(connection), &event);
    } else {
        printf("epoll_ctl() error: %u: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Another option would be to enable or disable ssl permanently, add `sslmode=require` or `sslmode=disable` to your connect string for this. But if you plan to use `PGreset()` (or encounter any other situation where the socket is closed and reopened transparently to the caller), you will have the same problem then.

Admittedly, this behaviour of the postgresql-client-library is not very `epoll()`-friendly. In the old times, when using `select()` or `poll()`, this was a non-issue, because there was no state in kernel like with `epoll()` now.